# What should be used instead of Open Activities in apex:relatedList tag in VF?

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to build a page where the related list tag is showing the below Error. Request your help in resolving this issue.

**Visualforce Error**

**'Open Activities' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Account**

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="ListLead" sidebar="false">
<apex:pageBlock title="{!Account.Name}">
  <apex:tabPanel switchType="ajax">
    <apex:tab label="Details" labelwidth="180">
      <apex:detail relatedList="false" title="true"/>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Contacts" labelwidth="180">
      <apex:relatedlist list="Contacts"/>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Opportunities" labelwidth="180">
      <apex:relatedlist list="Opportunities"/>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Cases" labelwidth="180">
      <apex:relatedlist list="Cases"/>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Open Activities" labelwidth="180">
      <apex:relatedlist list="Open Activities"/>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Notes & Attachments" labelwidth="180">
      <apex:relatedlist list="Notes & Attachments"/>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Leads" labelwidth="180">
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!lstld}" var="l">
        <apex:column value="{!l.FirstName}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!l.LastName}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!l.Company}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!l.Email}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:tab>
  </apex:tabPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: They're API Names...you would never have one with space characters nor ampersands...

Answer (score 1):

To find out, go to the API page in setup and generate a WSDL. This will give you a list of all of the api names for the standard objects and their relationships (or use the schema explorer if you have eclipse installed).

In the WSDL ctrl+f for

> <**complexType** name="**Account**">

Then scroll through til you find the relationship you're looking for:

> <**element** **name="OpenActivities"** nillable="true"
>   minOccurs="0" **type="tns:QueryResult"**/>

(bolded the parts of the XML tags you should be paying attention to)

The name should be **OpenActivities**

**Note:**

You will run into a few instances where the related list tag won't work. I believe Email Message on case is an example of such instance; I believe the history list is also not accessible this way. In these cases you have to code out the related list.

Use Chrome's HTML inspector to get an idea of the markup output and the class names used for styling to get close to the desired result. I believe I used pageblocksection with pageblocktable elements to match the markup.

Add a column that is only visible when no records are displayed and give it a class like "emptycolumn" or something (find this using the inspector as listed above) to match the style of empty lists.

SFDC styles most of it's elements in a hierarchy so you can't just put the styleclass onto these elements, you'll have to wrap them in some divs to make sure they have the proper parent elements as well or the style wont get applied.